# Peskin and Schroeder chapter 5 - going from gamma matrices to sigma

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, spinors

I am trying to recreate all steps from 5.97 to 5.103. Can someone explain how to go from 5.97 to 5.99 ? I understand the denominator part, my issue is with the transformation from gamma to sigma matrices

[image]

Comment: Hi @Holographysicist and welcome to PSE. Have you tried substituting $\gamma^{\mu}$ with a 2x2 matrix whose off-diagonal elements are the 2x2 matrices $\sigma^{\mu}$ and $\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies in the fact that
$$\gamma^{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\mu} \\
\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\sigma^{\mu}=(1,\sigma^i),\ \bar{\sigma}^{\mu}=(1,-\sigma^i)$. Then, you must consider the product
$$\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\nu}(p-k')_{\rho}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\mu} \\
\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\rho} \\
\bar{\sigma}^{\rho} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\nu} \\
\bar{\sigma}^{\nu} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
(p-k')_{\rho}\\=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\rho} & 0 \\
0 &  \bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\sigma^{\rho}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\nu} \\
\bar{\sigma}^{\nu} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
(p-k')_{\rho}\\=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\rho}\sigma^{\nu} \\
\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\sigma^{\rho}\bar{\sigma}^{\nu} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
(p-k')_{\rho}$$
Now, if one chooses the initial electron to be right handed, i.e. $u(p)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
u_R(p)
\end{pmatrix}$, with $u_R(p)$ being the one given in Eq. (5.100), then the dominant term of Eq. (5.97), coming from the term involving the $\gamma^{\rho}(p-k')_{\rho}$ term (as opposed to the mass term), yields
$$\bar{u}(p')\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\nu}(p-k')_{\rho}u_R(p)=
\begin{pmatrix}
u^{\dagger}_R(p) &
u^{\dagger}_L(p)  
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\rho}\sigma^{\nu} \\
\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\sigma^{\rho}\bar{\sigma}^{\nu} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
u_R(p)  
\end{pmatrix}
(p-k')_{\rho}\\=
u^{\dagger}_R(p)
\sigma^{\mu}
\bar{\sigma}\cdot (p-k')
\sigma^{\nu}
u_R(p)$$
where I have used that $\bar{u}(p)=u^{\dagger}(p)\gamma^0$ and that the final electron could, in principle, have both left-handed and right-handed components (with one of them not contribtuting at all to the final result)...

If there are more questions, please let me know.